# How to store state of Matrix for each instance of a Model in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I have the next code partially working, to draw the Model, 
I'm creating several instances of it and rendering each instance of the model to a diferent rendertarget. 
My question is How can I store the matrix for each instance? because when I want to rotate one, it seems that is taking a reference of the matrix and when rotating it takes an updated matrix.
Thanks.
Regards

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
    using gamacherclone.Sources.Model;

namespace gamacherclone
{
    public class Case360 : DrawableComponent 
    {
        private Model _model ;//= new Model();
        Matrix[] _boneTransforms,world;
        public int coverflowposition = 0;
        public bool rotate = false;
        Matrix view,  proj,worldtransform,tempbones;
        public Matrix[] boneTransforms;
        public Matrix[] originalBoneTransforms;
        Matrix[] worldTransforms;
        float i = 0;

        public DashBoard dash;
        Cover cover;


        public Case360(Game game, Cover _cover)
            : base(game)
        {
            this.dash = (DashBoard)game;
            this.cover = _cover;
        }

        protected override void LoadContent(){
            this._model = this.dash.Content.Load<Model>(@"Models\case360");
            this.initialize();  
         }
        public void initialize() {

            this._boneTransforms = new Matrix[this._model.Bones.Count];
            this.originalBoneTransforms = new Matrix[this._model.Bones.Count];
            this.worldTransforms = new Matrix[this._model.Bones.Count];
            this._model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(_boneTransforms);
            this._model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(originalBoneTransforms);
        }



        public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {

            // Calculate the new position of the forks.
            float time = (float)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalSeconds;

           if (this.rotate) {
                worldtransform = worldTransforms[0];
                UpdateWorldTransforms(time);
            }


            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        public void UpdateWorldTransforms(float time)
        {

            worldTransforms[0] = _boneTransforms[0] * Matrix.CreateRotationY(time * 2f);

        }


        public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            this._model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(_boneTransforms);
             base.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(cover.caseRender);
             base.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Transparent);
             base.GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
             //GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = RasterizerState.CullCounterClockwise;
             base.GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

             view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(new Vector3(1, 10, 10), new Vector3(0, 7, -10), Vector3.Up);
             proj = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(MathHelper.ToRadians(45f),
                                        GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height,
                                        1f, 1000.0f);


            // Draw the model.

            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in this._model.Meshes)
            {
               foreach (BasicEffect mesheffect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    mesheffect.Parameters["Texture"].SetValue(this.cover.coverImage);
                    mesheffect.EnableDefaultLighting();

                    mesheffect.View = view;
                    mesheffect.Projection = proj;
                    mesheffect.World = worldtransform;

                }

                mesh.Draw();
            }

            base.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);
            base.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(dash.renderTarget2D);
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you are using the variable `worldtransform` on the following line

```
mesheffect.World = worldtransform;
```

and setting that value at Update: `worldtransform = worldTransforms[0];`

The problem you are having is that [Matrix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.matrix.aspx) is a struct, and will be passed by value (not reference).  So when you assign the array matrix `worldTransforms[0]` to the variable `worldtransform` you are creating an entirely new instance.

You can fix this by doing:

```
UpdateWorldTransforms(time);
worldtransform = worldTransforms[0];
```

OR Pass a matrix by reference and modify the variable directly

```
public void UpdateWorldTransforms(float time, ref Matrix worldMatrix)
{
    worldMatrix = _boneTransforms[0] * Matrix.CreateRotationY(time * 2f);
}
```

**Update**:

As for the storing multiple instances you could use a model like so:

```
public class WorldObject
{
    public Matrix World { get; set; }
    public Model GameModel { get; set; }
}
```

And store additional information in that class.  It could handle update/drawing information and perform actions on the World transform.

Look into 'XNA instancing' but some of it might be more than you need

- [Instanced Model](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/mesh_instancing)
- [Hardware Instancing](http://www.float4x4.net/index.php/2010/06/hardware-instancing-in-xna/)
- [Skinned Model Instancing](http://ionixxgames.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/xna-sample-skinned-model-instancing/)